# RadioButton List selecting only as default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have this scenario:

```
public class Manager {

    public int DefaultDistributorId { get; set; }
    public List<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }
}

public class Distributor {

    public int DistributorId { get; set; }
    public string DistributorName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a radiobutton list based on each distributor from the collection above. When I select some distributor, I want to fill the `DefaultDistributorId` property into Manager entity. How can I do that?

```
@for (int count = 0; count < Model.Distributors.Count; ++count) {

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DefaultDistributorId,
        Model.Distributors[count].DistributorId);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What efforts have you taken?

Comment: I've putted a `RadioButtonFor` for each item on distributors list, but how to link it to `DefaultDistributorId` property?

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TheAction", "TheController"))
{
    foreach (Distributor t in Model.Distributors)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DefaultDistributorId, t.DistributorId)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Manager model)
{
    // You have selected Distributor in model.DefaultDistributorId
}
```